# How can I find documentation to explain how to_utc_timestamp defines Central Standard Time timezone in spark databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, timezone, databricks

I am expecting UST to be always 6 hours ahead of CST. Apparently spark disagrees.

```
spark.sql("""select to_utc_timestamp('2022-02-26 17:35:36', "CST") """).show()
```

```
+-------------------+
|               time|
+-------------------+
|2022-02-26 23:35:36|
+-------------------+
```

```
spark.sql("""select to_utc_timestamp('2021-08-26 17:35:36', "CST") """).show()
```

```
+-------------------+
|               time|
+-------------------+
|2021-08-26 22:35:36|
+-------------------+
```

Is there some documentation that explains exactly how which timezone is calculated ? I could only find the [function documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_utc_timestamp.html).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the best way to understand exactly how Spark-SQL functions work is to dig through the source code, starting from [org.apache.spark.sql.functions](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala) and following the breadcrumbs until you wind up [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/37dbf1cc99ab888342d04b0bf41619ff597ddab9/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala#L1054), which will show you that Spark is using the standard java.time.* classes under the hood.

This isn't going to help in your case, however, because the problem is your assumption. Java's `TimeZone` for CST respects daylight savings time, which will give you a different offset depending upon the `DateTime` you give it. You can provide a fixed offset yourself, e.g.

```
spark.sql("""select to_utc_timestamp('2022-02-26 17:35:36', "-0600") """).show()
```

but I'm unaware of any way to automatically ignore daylight savings in this context.

Comment: Thank you for the help ! there is something called CDT for central daylight time and i thought that was the daylight saving time